# verify x509 certificate validity at some point of time

Tags: php, openssl, pkcs#7

Actually what I am trying to do is to verify signature of the file. It consists of several items:

1. Verify that file hash is the same as in signature (non-modification)
2. Verify that certificate chain is valid (it is done using OCSP and
   cached CRLs)
3. Verify that certificate was valid at given time. Now
   this is the problem. I can't get this information using both `OCSP`
   or `CRL`.

Can you point me to direction how can this be checked?